# Dismiss a Modal View Controller(floating panel) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller

I am using this library as my [floating panel](https://github.com/scenee/FloatingPanel).

i have two view controllers.

1. home view controller
2. floatingPanel view controller.

in home view controller there is a calendar that select the date. when the date is selected i call for the floatingPanel view controller.

```
   func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    log.success("date has been selected")/
       
    day = formatter.string(from: date)
   // presenting the modal view controller
       let fpc = FloatingPanelController()
       fpc.delegate = self
       
       guard let floatingPannel = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contentPannel") as? floatingPannel else {
           return
       }
       
    fpc.set(contentViewController: floatingPannel)
    fpc.addPanel(toParent: self)
   
      
   }
```

after loading the floating panel i am using the deselect method in the calendar to dismiss the presented modal view.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didDeselect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    // dismiss the current modal view
}
```

i want to dismiss the current modal view from inside this function. is there any way i can do it.

Comment: `calendar.dismiss(animated: true)`

Comment: i want to dismiss the floatingPannel .

Comment: You need to declare your fpc as an instance property of your view controller and call fpc.dismiss from any method you want. Resuming move your fpc declaration out of calendar didSelect method

Comment: can you guide me about how to create an instance property of view controller. i am new for the swift. i have google it but didn't find a way to creating it, that i can understand.

Comment: Just move  `let fpc = FloatingPanelController()` to the line above `func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare fpc as an instance property of your view controller.

```
let fpc = FloatingPanelController()
```

then

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {

    day = formatter.string(from: date)
       
       guard let floatingPannel = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contentPanel") as? floatingPannel else {
           return
       }
       fpc.set(contentViewController: floatingPannel)
       fpc.addPanel(toParent: self)
   }
```

you can dismiss the view from

```
 func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didDeselect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
    
    fpc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```